# Сохранять token в shared preference

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, android-shared-preferences, token

Есть сервис (firebase), в котором я обращаюсь к token'у.

```
    override fun onTokenRefresh() {
    super.onTokenRefresh()
    val refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().token
}
```

Если я правильно таким образом я получаю конкретный token. Его сохраняю в SharePreferences:

```
 private val preferences: SharedPreferences?
    get() = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(AppResources.context)
var secretToken: String
get() = preferences?.getString(KEY_TOKEN, "") ?: ""
set(value) {
    preferences?.saveValue(KEY_TOKEN, value)
}
```

Но дальше читая офф документацию, мне предлагают этот токен отправлять на сервер, мне это подходит, но как правильно можно это реализовать в методе `sendRegistrationToServer()` - [ссылка](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/master/messaging/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/fcm/MyFirebaseInstanceIDService.java#L38) с офф док.

Comment: А вопрос в чём?

Comment: Ну как бэ сохранять секретный токен в преферансах я бы поостерегся...

Comment: @eugeneek обновил вопрос, по тихонечку двигаюсь к правильному решению)

Comment: @Barmaley да Вы правы. но сейчас основная идея отработать flow, после буду использовать Realm для сохранения токена

Comment: А зачем его вообще сохранять, если его всегда можно получить, обратившись `FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().token`?

Answer (score 1):

Ну в принципе вроде всё верно, так я так понял вы хотите проверить что что либо сохранили? Если так то после запуска эммулятора, можете запустить Android Device Monitor и дальше двигаться по этому мини гайду [ссылка на гайд](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45392716/6387618). Также как хорошая практика написать тест, и посмотреть сохраняются ли ожидаемые значения в SP.

P.S. как примечание, перепишите с использованием композиции вместо getDefaultSharedPreferences и напишите тест.(DIP)

Comment: Спасибо, данное решение частично помогло, обновил вопрос.
Примечание P.S. не совсем понятно(композиция DIP?)